# Google Chrome freezes on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Chrome intermittently freezes on my Mac.

Some people say it is due to corrupted user profile files.

Anyone knows how to fix this? Any ready tool for that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try going to

```
YOUR_HOME_FOLDER/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome
```

and deleting everything there.Then reinstall Chrome.

Comment: There is Google folder but not Chrome. I am running mac 10.7.5

Comment: Is there anything in the Google folder

Comment: two programs
1) Google Talk Plugin
2) Google Voice and Video uninstaller

Comment: Path where it is located is ROOT/Library/Application Support/Google

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check, if you don't have the plugins double enabled.

I use both Chrome and Chromium. Chromium was running into problems. It turned out that I had (somehow) the plugins double enabled.

---

```
Google Talk (4 files)
Name:   Google Talk Plugin
Version:    
Location:   /usr/lib/chromium-browser/pepper/libppgoogletalk.so
Type:   PPAPI (unsandboxed)
     Disable
MIME types: 
MIME type   Description File extensions
application/googletalk  Google Talk Plugin  
..googletalk
Name:   Google Talk Plugin Video Renderer
Version:    
Location:   /usr/lib/chromium-browser/pepper/libppo1d.so
Type:   PPAPI (unsandboxed)
     Disable
MIME types: 
MIME type   Description File extensions
application/o1d Google Talk Plugin Video Renderer   
.
Name:   Google Talk Plugin
Description:    Version: 5.4.1.0
Version:    
Location:   /opt/google/talkplugin/libnpgoogletalk.so
Type:   NPAPI
     Enable
MIME types: 
MIME type   Description File extensions
application/googletalk  Google Talk Plugin  
.googletalk
Name:   Google Talk Plugin Video Renderer
Description:    Version: 5.4.1.0
Version:    
Location:   /opt/google/talkplugin/libnpo1d.so
Type:   NPAPI
     Enable
MIME types: 
MIME type   Description File extensions
application/o1d Google Talk Plugin Video Renderer   
.o1d
```

---

- Go to chrome://plugins/
- Click on (+) to see the details.
- Disable the Google plugins (in my case "/opt/google/talkplugin/") and keep the Chromium ones (in my case "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/pepper/").